# Haskell - Couldn't match type ‘GHC.IsList.Item Char’ with ‘Char’

Tags: haskell

I have a function which pads out a string

```hs
pad :: Int -> String -> String
```

and I am trying to convert it to a stream type I built which implements `GHC.IsList`, this doesn't work, and I'm getting a type error I don't know what to do with

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘GHC.IsList.Item Char’ with ‘Char’
      Expected: [GHC.IsList.Item Char]
        Actual: String
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘pad maxLen x’
      In the expression: fromList $ pad maxLen x
```

I have implemented the type family as `type Item (Stream a) = a`, so these should logically be equivalent, but the compiler does not believe they are equivalent and no amount of annotating I've tried has convinced it that they are.

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of the `pad` that results in this error?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem The implementation doesn't matter, surely? The type error is in a *call* to `pad`, and we're given `pad`'s type signature, so what happens inside it is immaterial. As I say in my answer, there is other information that would be useful, but not the implementation of `pad`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to know what type GHC thinks this expression should have to be sure, but if you've given the type of `pad` correctly, it looks to me like the problem doesn't lie in the code you've posted. Rather, GHC has inferred a type for this expression that doesn't match, because of some error elsewhere.

For example, you would get an error like this if you wrote

```
pad :: Int -> String -> String
pad = undefined

c :: Char
c = fromList $ pad 20 "abcd"
```

Here GHC has deduced that `fromList` must return `Char`, but of course it can't because there is no `instance IsList Char`.